# Folders and path structure for Ghost posts rendered with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, ghost-blog

I'm using Ghost as a headless CMS for Gatsby, and I want to create a path structure for my site, e.g. `/foo/bar` and `/foo/baz`, where `bar` and `baz` are the slugs for the Ghost posts.

What's the recommended way to handle directories with Ghost? Ghost doesn't even seem to support the concept - it only has flat posts or pages. It supports [routes](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/routing/routes/) but via Handlebars templates, and I'm using Gatsby to render the site.

I can think of designating some special character (e.g. `_`) as a path separator in Ghost slugs, then splitting by that in `gatsby-node.js` but that's not very elegant.

Comment: Do you want every page to be under `/foo/`?

Comment: @ksav: No. I want multiple paths, like in any decent CMS. Some pages should be under `/foo`, others under `/news`, etc.

Comment: And where do you intend to store this path information?

Comment: @ksav: Since Ghost doesn't have a mechanism for paths, I'd be happy to store that information as a directory structure that would be reflected in the path; or in another recommended way, if there is one easier to manipulate than code.